# Iterable Mapping- how to retreive all the values with For-Loop?

Tags: for-loop, mapping, solidity, smartcontracts

From looking at the code below can anyone show me how you'd write a for loop to get all the values in the mapping? Thanks in advance for the help.

````
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract IterableMapping {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => bool) public inserted;
    address[] public keys;

    function set(address _addr, uint _bal) external {
        balances[_addr] = _bal;

        if (!inserted[_addr]) {
            inserted[_addr] = true;
            keys.push(_addr);
        }
    }

    function get(uint _index) external view returns (uint) {
        address key = keys[_index];
        return balances[key];
    }

    function first() external view returns (uint) {
        return balances[keys[0]];
    }

    function last() external view returns (uint) {
        return balances[keys[keys.length - 1]];
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

oh i see my mistake now with trying to get the bool values. it would be...

```
function getAllBools() public view returns (bool[] memory) {
    bool[] memory result = new bool[](keys.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        result[i] = inserted[keys[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through balances by using address as key , hereby you will get All the values in the balances Mapping.

```
  function getAllBalances() public view returns (uint[] memory){
    uint[] memory result = new uint[](keys.length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        result[i] = balances[keys[i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Likewise you can also get values of the inserted mapping

Comment: Thanks. Greatly appreciate the help. What you mentioned about getting the values of the inserted mapping? I am assuming you mean the bool values? I tried the following in Remix but got some errors saying "type bool is not convertible to uint256). I guess i am doing something wrong here with the inserted[keys[i]]; line?? 
<br/>
`
function getAllBools() public view returns (bool[] memory) {
        uint[] memory result = new uint[](keys.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            result[i] = inserted[keys[i]];
        }
        return result;
    }
'